# Center Excel Cell Content using Excel Interop w/ C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to center the values of the cells that will be used as headers.  This is the code I am currently using to format these cells already.  I am using the Excel Interop with C#.  How do I center the values in this range of cells.

```
public void createHeaders(int row, int col, string htext, string cell1,
    string cell2, int mergeColumns, string b, bool font, int size, string
    fcolor)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, col] = htext;
        workSheet_range = worksheet.get_Range(cell1, cell2);
        workSheet_range.Merge(mergeColumns);
        switch (b)
        {
            case "BLUE":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red.ToArgb();
                break;
            case "GAINSBORO":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color =
        System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro.ToArgb();
                break;
            //case "Turquoise":
               // workSheet_range.Interior.Color =
        //System.Drawing.Color.Turquoise.ToArgb();
                //break;
            case "PeachPuff":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color =
        System.Drawing.Color.PeachPuff.ToArgb();
                break;
            default:
                //  workSheet_range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color..ToArgb();
                break;
        }

        //workSheet_range.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black.ToArgb();
        //workSheet_range.Borders = null;
        workSheet_range.Font.Bold = font;
        workSheet_range.ColumnWidth = size;
        workSheet_range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FloralWhite.ToArgb();

    }
```

Comment: How do I get the values centered for this range of cells?

Comment: Read the value from the first cell in the range.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the `ContentAlignment` enum is from System.Drawing and does not apply to Excel ranges.  try

```
workSheet_range.HorizontalAlignment =
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
```